# Error : Null Pointer Exception on MutableLiveData

Tags: java, android, viewmodel, android-livedata

I try to build a Timer with livedata and ViewModel. An AndroidViewModel has been used to get context and the same has been passed to CountDownTimer . After each interval the same is passed to the the mainActivity using livData
This is the error that I face :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATA

L EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.testproject, PID: 7818
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.testproject.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Below is the main Class

Main class:

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            MyObserver myObserver;
        
            TextView textView;
            MainViewModel mViewModel;
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
                textView = findViewById(R.id.textViewGoal);
                mViewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication()).create(MainViewModel.class);
            }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mViewModel.liveData.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(String s) {
                  textView.setText(s);
    
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And this is the ViewModel Class

```
ViewModel class:

    public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
        MutableLiveData<String> liveData;
    
        public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
            super(application);
            startTimer();
        }
    
        void startTimer(){
            CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(20000,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {
                    liveData.postValue(String.valueOf(l/1000));
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
    
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are calling `liveData.postValue(String.valueOf(l/1000));` without ever instanstiating the `liveData` 

Change this 
`MutableLiveData<String> liveData;` to 
`MutableLiveData<String> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();`

Comment: Try observing the livedata in onViewCreated

Comment: @blongho thx. I completely forgot about i :0